# Iframe hiding and no solution works

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I making my own film-webspace on my pc and there I have to buttons to show a the cover of the film and one to hide the cover and show the iframe but that doesnt work. Here my code:

My php Code for the cover and iframe:

```
    echo '<div class="BildTrailerButton">';
               echo '<button name="Bild" id="Bildbutton" value="Cover" onClick="bild()">'."Cover".'</button>';
               echo '<button name="Trailer" id="Trailerbutton" value="Trailer" onClick="trailer()">'."Trailer".'</button>';
               echo '</div>';


               echo '<img src="'.$titel['Bilderlink'].'" title="'.$titel['FTitel'].'" class="Filmbilder" id="Bild">';

               echo '<div class="videoDiv" id="playerDiv">';
               echo '<iframe width="560" height="400" src="'.$titel['Trailerlink'].'" frameborder="0" id="player" allowfullscreen>';
               echo '</iframe>';

               echo '</div>';
```

and here the code of the javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" defer>

        document.getElementById("player").style.visibility="hidden";

        function trailer(){             
                document.getElementById("Bild").style.visibility="hidden";
                document.getElementById("player").style.visibility="visible";

        }  

        function bild(){
                document.getElementById("player").style.visibility="hidden";
                document.getElementById("Bild").style.visibility="visible";        
        }


    </script>
```

The firebug console gives this error:

```
    TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
document.getElementById("player").style.visibility="hidden";
```

Comment: Is the source URL of the iframe on the same domain as this document? If it's not the browser will prohibit access to the iframe tag as a security measure.

Comment: The iframe src is a youtube link.

Comment: Is there any chance to hide my iframe?

Comment: And thus you don't have access to the iframe tag. Best way to deal with that is to actually use the embed code of the YouTube movie and insert that in a <div> tag. You'll always have access to that tag, so you can hide that at your will.

Comment: @Plenka: Of course you have access to the iframe _element_ itself – the SOP only prevents you from access to its _content_.

Answer (score 0):

Hide iframe with:

```
document.getElementById("player").style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone especially Plenka. I made it :)
Here my new code:

The Javascript:

```
     <script type="text/javascript" defer>



        function trailer(){             
                document.getElementById("Bild").style.visibility="hidden";
                document.getElementById("playerDiv").style.visibility="visible";

        }  

        function bild(){
                document.getElementById("playerDiv").style.visibility="hidden";
                document.getElementById("Bild").style.visibility="visible";        
        }


    </script>
```

And the html/php code:

```
    echo '<div class="BildTrailerButton">';
               echo '<button name="Bild" id="Bildbutton" value="Cover" onClick="bild()">'."Cover".'</button>';
               echo '<button name="Trailer" id="Trailerbutton" value="Trailer" onClick="trailer()">'."Trailer".'</button>';
               echo '</div>';


               echo '<img src="'.$titel['Bilderlink'].'" title="'.$titel['FTitel'].'" class="Filmbilder" id="Bild">';

               echo '<div class="videoDiv" id="playerDiv">';
               echo '<object width="560" height="315">'
                   .'<param name="movie" value="'.$titel['Trailerlink'].'"></param>'
                   .'<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>'
                   .'<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>'
                   .'<embed src="'.$titel['Trailerlink'].'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="400" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>'
                   .'</object>';      
               echo '</div>';
           }
```